# How to call a VHDL function written in a seperate file to a C program

Tags: c, vhdl

Say I have a function written in VHDL and I want to call it from C and execute it in the C program. How would I do that?

A simple example would be helpful. I searched and found [this book](https://books.google.lk/books?id=uAIwcAKo_VIC&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=linking%20C%20and%20HDL%20files&source=bl&ots=e02fP1FN2B&sig=CGLceDC1pXzJkP1ZM1ALXkVxFeY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizoJ-IheTMAhUHuRQKHaJwCnMQ6AEINjAE#v=onepage&q=linking%20C%20and%20HDL%20files&f=false), but it only shows how to call C functions from VHDL, not the other way round.

Can I include the VHDL code i want to implement in a device driver?.Using a tool like xilinx XPS a device driver can be made and the bitstream can be downloaded to an FPGA to make the hardware configurations .So in the end the C files will run in the microblaze and the VHDL implementation will be in the FPGA as a device driver.Can I call the driver then to the C file? because what i wanna do is to implement part of a C code in VHDL the rest of course in C and offload it to an FPGA and check whether the latency is reduced.Im using the pppd source code for this project.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. About all you can do is launch a simulation using the `system` function, or you could `fork` and `exec` a simulation. This assumes, of course, that you have a command-line-driven simulator on your system.

Comment: Why do you want to call a C function from VHDL? VHDL is no programming language ... If you are looking for the VHPI interface, which allows you to bind external sub programs to the simulator and interact with your hardware model, then please clarify your question.

Comment: can i include the VHDL code i want to implement  in a device driver.Using a tool like xilinx XPS  a device driver can be made and the  bitstream can be downloaded to an FPGA to make the hardware configurations .So in the end the C files will  run in the microblaze and the VHDL  implementation will be  in the FPGA as device driver.Can i call the driver then to the C file? because what i wanna do is to implement part of a C code in VHDL the rest of course in C and offload it to an FPGA and check whether the latency is reduced.

Comment: what  i wanna do is to implement part of the pppd source code in VHDL and keep the rest in C as it is and put the whole thing to an FPGA and check whether the latency is reduced

Comment: @Deepal Yes, if the C code is running on the FPGA, then you can certainly use VHDL to design the rest of the FPGA. You'll need to define a set of registers that the C code uses to send/retrieve information to/from the hardware. Typically, those are memory mapped registers, but I don't have any detailed information about how that works with the MicroBlaze architecture.

Comment: @Paebbels I have to disagree. Your design is hardware, no question, but I would say (and teach) that your testbench is software (it never leaves your computer). Look at SystemVerilog: the majority of that language has nothing to do with hardware (eg OO for a start). There are many reasons to call a C function from your testbench: you have a reference model in C; you want better file I/O; you want to interact with the OS; you want graphical output... Look again at SystemVerilog: it's very easy to call C from SystemVerilog; it's pretty easy to call SystemVerilog functions and tasks from C.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I know that, but VHDL is no general purpose programming language and the question is pointing in the direction of using VHDL like C... The second part of my comment focuses on testbench use cases ;).

Comment: @Matthew Taylor -any document that has simple examples of SystemVerilog functions being called from C would be helpful.

Comment: We can only comment now, because 5 people WHO APPEAR TO HAVE NO KNOWLEDGE OF THE SUBJECT have deemed it "too broad". You can call C functions from SystemVerilog using the DPI: you need to `import` your C function: If you do that, you can `export` any SystemVerilog function or task and can call that from the C function you imported (which must be imported using `context`). Here's a [document](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/dpi/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926630/using-c-programming-to-call-vhdl-implementation

Comment: Your extra edit suggests you have a fundamental misunderstanding about what is going on here (and we had a fundamental misunderstanding of what you were asking and why). I suggest you look at the duplicate linked above.

Comment: Yeah thankx got it

Answer (score 1):

The only standard interface between VHDL and other languages is the VHPI (new in the VHDL-2008 standard).  There is a Modelsim specific interface called the FLI.

However, all of these languages are for VHDL to C/C++.  As far as I can tell, there is no mechanism to call a subprogram from C/C++ into VHDL.  And I have researched it extensively.

Depending upon the tool in use, it may be possible to call VHDL subprograms from SystemC or SystemVerilog (via `SC_IMPORT` or `import "DPI-C"`, respectively), in my experience this support is very limited and very tool dependent (usually only available in very high-end commercial tools).

Now, if you want to implement some of pppd, you'd be better off implementing it via an `entity`/`architecture` pair, and then instantiating it in a SystemVerilog or SystemC environment and passing data into the VHDL entity via the given ports.  Or if you insist on it being as a subprogram, use SystemVerilog or SystemC instead for implementation.

Comment: Are you experienced in VHPI? The IEEE P1076 working group seeks for knowledge in extending VHPI...

Comment: @Paebbels I do.  In fact, prior to cocotb, I had implemented an internal tool for my company to integrate Python (and optionally Lua) into VHDL testbenches.  But as I pointed out in my answer (which somebody strangely downvoted), there was no way to call into VHDL from a foreign language.  Rather, the workaround was to register foreign subprograms and certain callbacks.   There is no VHPI method to invoke a subprogram.

Comment: @PlayDough I have been trying to contact the man responsible for cocotb re upgrading the version on EDA Playground following a request for me to do so, but since the initial request have received no further replies.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I think previous comment was unclear. I am not affiliated with cocotb.  What I meant to say was "Prior to somebody creating cocotb, I had implemented ...."  I don't have any knowledge of the state of cocotb or its maintenance.